# Add QAction to the QMenuBar dynamically outside of window constructor (get access to ui generated in Designer from another file)

Tags: c++, qt, qaction

How can I add some action to the QMenuBar outside of window constructor?

I have got some `ui_menu.h` file created in QtDesigner with QMenuBar:

```
#ifndef UI_MENU_H
#define UI_MENU_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtWidgets/QHeaderView>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenu>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenuBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QStatusBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_MainWindow
{
public:
    QAction *actionTtt;
    QWidget *centralwidget;
    QMenuBar *menubar;
    QMenu *menuViev;
    QStatusBar *statusbar;

    void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
        if (MainWindow->objectName().isEmpty())
            MainWindow->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("MainWindow"));
        MainWindow->resize(800, 600);
        actionTtt = new QAction(MainWindow);
        actionTtt->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("actionTtt"));
        centralwidget = new QWidget(MainWindow);
        centralwidget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("centralwidget"));
        MainWindow->setCentralWidget(centralwidget);
        menubar = new QMenuBar(MainWindow);
        menubar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("menubar"));
        menubar->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 800, 21));
        menuViev = new QMenu(menubar);
        menuViev->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("menuFile"));
        MainWindow->setMenuBar(menubar);
        statusbar = new QStatusBar(MainWindow);
        statusbar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("statusbar"));
        MainWindow->setStatusBar(statusbar);

        menubar->addAction(menuFile->menuAction());
        menuViev->addAction(actionTtt);

        retranslateUi(MainWindow);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MainWindow);
    } // setupUi


};

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow: public Ui_MainWindow {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_MENU_H
```

and in `menu.cpp` create class of that window:

```
Menu::Menu(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}
```

In this class I need a function that will add QAction to the QMenuBar

```
void Menu::AddSubMenu()
{
    actionFirst = new QAction(this);
    actionFirst->setObjectName("actionFirst");
    menuBar->addAction(menuViev->menuAction());
    menuViev->addAction(actionFirst);
}
```

But it shows exeption about: Access violation reading at...

Comment: something's missing, `menuView` looks like a `QMenu` but it's not declared (in the code you posted)

Comment: @LogicStuff made changes to the code. It just some 'QMenu'  from 'QMenuBar' declareted in ui_menu.h

Comment: @LogicStuff Or I just think so. How can I add this Qaction to  'QMenu' from 'QMenuBar' declareted in ui_menu.h?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created menu "Viev" in `menuBar` usnig QtDesigner then you do not need this line:

`ui->menuBar->addAction(ui->menuView->menuAction());`

This code works for me:

```
void Menu::AddSubMenu()
{
    QAction *actionFirst = new QAction(this);
    actionFirst->setObjectName("actionFirst");
    actionFirst->setText("Test");
    ui->menuView->addAction(actionFirst);
}
```

Comment: You are wrigh, this almost works, i just need a pointer for ui class
`Ui::MainWindow *pui = &ui;
pui->menuViev->addAction(actionFirst);`

Answer (score 0):

To help other people understand what is ui. It is Class declareted in menu.h:

```
#include "ui_menu.h"
class Menu: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
....

private:
    Ui::MainWindow ui;
```